# Why would the Jacobian not be zero in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, determinant

Find the jacobian of the transformation x = u, y = 3uv in the uv plane.

Why would $U_y$ not be zero in this case, if the equation U = x contains no mentions of y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jacobian is 
$$ \frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)} = \left[ \begin{matrix} \displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\[6pt] \displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \displaystyle\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \end{matrix} \right] = \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\3v & 3u \end{matrix} \right] $$

You were trying to find $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, which would be part of the reverse Jacobian (from $uv$ to $xy$)

Answer (score 2):

What is $U_y$? The jacobian matrix is

$J = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 3v & 3u\end{pmatrix}$

It's determinant is $3u$

Comment: The top right element of the jacobian matrix is the x partial of V. How did you calculate the x partial of V to be zero? Also, how did the lower left element (y partial of U) turn out to be 3v and not zero?

Comment: Revisit the definition of partial derivatives. When you take a partial derivative with respect to some variable, you consider all other variables to be constant except the one you derive for. $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{v}} = \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{v}}(u)  = 0$ since $u$ is held constant. Similarly, $\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{u}} = \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{u}}(3uv)  = 3v$.

Comment: Honestly I am still a bit confused as to how we calculate the top right. This is how I approached it: y = 3uv. -> y = 3xv. -> v = $\frac{y}{3x}$. $v_x$ = derivative with respect to x of $\frac{y}{3x}$

Answer (score 0):

Because y is a function of $x: y=3ux$(And viceversa), $u=x$, then $y=3xv $ and $x=y/3v$, so you get $u=y/3v$, so that $u$ is a non-constant function of $y$, and so $U_y \neq 0$.